# Android Screen Orientation

Tags: java, android

I am using both landscape and portrait for an application.

My problem is,whenever i rotate the screen,the TTS I am using in my application automatically

starts from first.

```
How do I solve this problem?
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Android restarts/recreates the activities whenever the **orientation** change.

You will need to save your `data/state` by calling `onSaveInstanceState()` before Android destroys the activities.

Have a look at [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

As the last resort, you could prevent this by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in **AndroidManifest** file.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation" should be last resort. use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() first.

Comment: My app  has all 4 layouts,i.e,small,normal,large and Xlarge. For Large and Xlarge I am using only Landscape and for small I am using only portrait by controlling it in java codes. For Normal I am using both Landscape and Portrait. So i  cant change my AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Mentioned Last resort is not your Last resort then... Go for the first option